# Construct a server object using grpc core libraries directly

Tags: c++, grpc

I want to implement a template class to wrap gRPC Server and Client, so that I can have a base interface for all services and clients of a project.

Is there a way to do that using gRPC core libraries? I searched through the documentation but I couldn't find anything related to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as asked:

The various gRPC sdks are all built on top of the core libraries, so it's entirely possible. Everything you need can be found in the `grpc/grpc.h` header

A simple-ish way to start going down that road would be to set the following environment variables, and run a gRPC app that behaves the way you want your custom server/client to.

```
GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
GRPC_TRACE=api
```

This will show you the sequence of core api calls that are being made, which you can use as a reference.

You can find more details here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md

That being said...

> so that I can have a base interface for all services and clients of a project.

That's not particularly hard to do with the C++ sdk either, and that would be a LOT less work than working with the core library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll definitely give a try to run a gRPC app with those environment variables! Could you suggest a way to have a base interface using C++ SDK? I'm struggling in finding a way using templates or macros, or a combination of both.

Comment: Do you have any implementation advice? I've tried to run a simple example of server/client with those variables set, but nothing was shown on terminal. @frank